# Retrieve countries timezones

Tags: time, api

What is the best way to retrieve the current time zones of a number of countries, on a daily basis? (that would take into account DST changes, of course)

- Reliably
- If possible the Linux way (i.e. either using internal resources, or a Linux website API)

*(I'm on Ubuntu 10.04)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want the timezone, then timezones are stored in `/usr/share/zoneinfo`.

If you want to be able to retrieve the *current time* for a number of different cities or countries, then you can pull them from the [Date and Time Gateway](http://twiki.org/cgi-bin/xtra/tzdatepick.html).

Answer (score 3):

You can simply do something like this:

```
$ TZ=Europe/Moscow date
Thu Jun  9 08:34:46 MSD 2011
$ TZ=America/NewYork date
Thu Jun  9 04:34:48 America 2011
```

You can find the zone names in `/usr/share/zoneinfo`. Of course, this requires that the machine you run this on has the correct time set.

(You can't really get the time by country, because a lot of countries have more than one timezone.)